# Стойка ли изображена на фото?

Tags: названия

Как называется этот предмет? Можно ли его назвать стойкой в значении "конструкция, предназначенная для удобного, компактного размещения предметов" (в данном случае флаеров). Можно ли назвать подставкой? Ведь они же располагаются на металлических решетках, как книжки на этажерке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это стенд.

> Место (щит, стойка и т.п.), где расположены экспонаты выставки,
>   диаграммы, картограммы и т.п. (спец.). [Толковый словарь Ушакова](https://slovar.cc/rus/ushakov/456387.html)